# safe multiple file to new multiple specific folder with same number python

Tags: python

Is there a way to save file to the new folder. So its like file1 save to folder1. And file2 save to folder2. And file3 to folder3. And this is my logic

```
filepath = "D:/Workspace/folder"

array = [1, 2, 3,...]

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(filepath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith("file*.txt"):
            path = dirname + '/' + filename
            Read = open(path, 'rb')
            for folder in array:
                path2 = dirname + '/' + str(folder) + '/' + filename
                Write = open(path2, 'w')
                path2.write(Read)
                if not os.path.exists(write):
                    os.makedirs(write)
```

And i only need to put if statement write "if the file1 already save in the folder1 then stop and continue to save file2 in the folder2 then stop, and so on"

But i don't know how to write that if else statement in coding.
I'll be very grateful for anyone that can helping me. Thankyou

Comment: Several issues there, not directly related to your Q, such as: `filename.endswith("file*.txt")` will **always** be false unless there's a literal star in the filename (unlikely!) == rather you need the `fnmatch` module.  Appending a number `folder` to several strings won't work (you need `str(folder)` -- and per your text, lose the `'/'` just before it, too!  That `save` function is mysterious.  Etc, etc.  Can you please fix your many obvious bugs by editing the question, that will make it MUCH easier to help you with your specific issue!

Comment: This is just the rough draft. Because I only need the logic for if statement. But I'll try to change it a bit. Thanks for your reply